# React Native: is it possible to achieve align-Item:flex-start style in React native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

Basically, I want to place a list of tags inside a View element, like below.

PS: the picture is from here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want the items to align `flex-start` and or you would like multiple items to align in a row like the `flex-start` image above? I ask because the default positioning in react-native flexbox is `flex-start`, but to get the items to align in a row like the image you have to declare `flexDirection:row`.

Comment: @NaderDabit: I want to have the tags (Texts of different lengths) to arrange first from left to right on a row, and then automatically swap to the next line ... etc. just like the first image shows.  Does your suggestion achieve the auto-swap part  ?

Comment: Yes, use `flexDirection: 'row'` and `flexWrap: 'wrap'` as stated above  in the parent container of the items you want to align and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, your parent container needs these attributes:

```
 flexDirection: 'row',
 flexWrap: 'wrap',
```

Working example: https://rnplay.org/apps/sa5G-Q